# Accessing a stage inside the parallel block in an AWS Step function from another branch

Tags: amazon-web-services, parallel-processing, workflow, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

[image]

I have created a step function as you can see in the picture. Now I need to execute StepX after StepK (And then the ChoiceA flow will end). So basically StepX should be executed in parallel with StepY->StepZ as it is now but also be executed after StepK. But I cannot find a way to access a stage which is inside a parallel block". Is there a way around this?

Here is my Json-

```
{
  "StartAt": "DataPointsExtractor",
  "States": {
    "DataPointsExtractor": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "PathDecider"
    },
    "PathDecider": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.path_type",
          "StringEquals": "ChoiceA",
          "Next": "ChoiceA"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.path_type",
          "StringEquals": "ChoiceB",
          "Next": "ChoiceB"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "NoMatchesState"
    },
    "ChoiceA": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "StepK"
    },
    "StepK": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "End": true
    },
    "ChoiceB": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "ParallelStates"
    },
    "ParallelStates": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "StepX",
          "States": {
            "StepX": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "StepY",
          "States": {
            "StepY": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
              "Next": "StepZ"
            },
            "StepZ": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    },
    "NoMatchesState": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "No Matches!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That is not Yaml, it is json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep it simple. As ChoiceA and ChoiceB are separate flows, they don't need to intersect. StepX can be used twice (you will have to use different name for it though)

[image]

**Definition:**

```
{
  "StartAt": "DataPointsExtractor",
  "States": {
    "DataPointsExtractor": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "PathDecider"
    },
    "PathDecider": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.path_type",
          "StringEquals": "ChoiceA",
          "Next": "ChoiceA"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.path_type",
          "StringEquals": "ChoiceB",
          "Next": "ChoiceB"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "NoMatchesState"
    },
    "ChoiceA": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "StepK"
    },
    "StepK": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "StepX"
    },
    "StepX": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "End": true
    },
    "ChoiceB": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
      "Next": "ParallelStates"
    },
    "ParallelStates": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "StepX",
          "States": {
            "StepX": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "StepY",
          "States": {
            "StepY": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
              "Next": "StepZ"
            },
            "StepZ": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:*******",
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    },
    "NoMatchesState": {
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "No Matches!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use the same name twice (Step X). This JSON is going to throw an error. But yeah I get your point. That is what I ended up implementing @amsh

Comment: @AbhisekRoy, you are right, I'm adding this clause in the answer. Same step names just explain the solution better.

Comment: Yeah yeah. In fact, when testing I tried doing it with the same name and then realised that is not allowed in AWS Step Functions. Anyway, I have accepted your answer. You can upvote my question if you think its a problem statement that Step function users come across often. Cheers. @amsh

Comment: @AbhisekRoy, affirmative.